# Error undefined reference to vtable MyClass

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Currency
{
    public:
        virtual double toRubles()const = 0;
        virtual void print()const;
};

class Dollar: public Currency
{
    private:
        double amount;
        double rate;
    public:
        Dollar(double A, double B)
            :amount(A)
            ,rate(B)
        {}
        Dollar()
            :amount(0)
            ,rate(0)
        {}
        double GetA()const{return amount;}
        double GetB()const{return rate;}
        void SetA(double A){amount=A;}
        void SetB(double B){rate=B;}

        double toRubles()const override
        {
            return amount*rate;
        }

        void print(const Dollar& dollar)
        {
            cout << "Dollar:\n";
            cout << "\t amount  = " << dollar.GetA() << endl;
            cout << "\t rate = " << dollar.GetB() << endl;
            cout << "\t Rubles to Dollar = " << dollar.toRubles() << endl;
        }
};
class Euro: public Currency
{
    private:
        double amount;
        double rate;
    public:
        Euro(double A, double B)
            :amount(A)
            ,rate(B)
        {}
        Euro()
            :amount(0)
            ,rate(0)
        {}
        double GetA()const{return amount;}
        double GetB()const{return rate;}
        void SetA(double A){amount=A;}
        void SetB(double B){rate=B;}

        double toRubles()const override
        {
            return amount*rate;
        }

        void print(const Euro& euro)const
        {
            cout << "Euro:\n";
            cout << "\t amount  = " << euro.GetA() << endl;
            cout << "\t rate = " << euro.GetB() << endl;
            cout << "\t Rubles to Euro = " << euro.toRubles() << endl;
        }

};

int main(){
    double a,b,c,d;
    cout << "Amount for DOLLAR:" ;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Rate for DOLLAR:" ;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Amount for EURO:" ;
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Amount for EURO:" ;
    cin >> d;
    Dollar dollar(a,b);
    Euro euro(c,d);

}
```

an error `undefined reference to vtable for Currency` and  `ld returned 1 exit status` occurs when compiling. without virtual functions, everything works, and when they are called, the program gives an error with the `print` method

the program must convert a specific value from Dollars and Euros to Rubles. The class `Currency` must have two virtual functions for conversion `toRubles` and then output `print` .

Comment: You didn't implement `Currency::print` even though you said you would.

Comment: in case you plan to use them polymorphically, you should also add a `virtual ~Currency()`

Comment: earlier i call it in main dollar.print() and euro.print() but it gives an error no mathing function for call to Dollar:print, so i dont understand how to call it in main. And when i override print it gives marked override but does not override

Comment: `virtual void print()const;` takes 0 parameters. For a method to override this method it must take 0 parameters

Comment: you are not passing an instance to the other members, why do you pass one to `print` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `virtual void print()const;` in Dollar and Euro classes exactly as it was declared in Currency. Also in Currency class that function must be defined or pure (= 0).